# Linking zeromq static library on solaris

Tags: c++, linker, g++, solaris, zeromq

I want to link the zeromq libraries in my build so they do not have to be installed separately on the end users machine.

I configured zeromq using:

```
./configure --enable-static --disable-shared --prefix=/home/xx/out
```

but when I do:

```
g++ -o zclient zmqclient.o /home/xx/out/lib/libzmq.a
```

I get linking errors:

```
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file

recv                                /opt/zmq/out/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-signaler.o)
send                                /opt/zmq/out/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-signaler.o)
__xnet_connect                      /opt/zmq/out/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-tcp_connecter.o)
__xnet_socket                       /opt/zmq/out/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o)
__xnet_getsockopt                   /opt/zmq/out/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-tcp_connecter.o)
accept                              /opt/zmq/out/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-tcp_listener.o)
listen                              /opt/zmq/out/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-tcp_listener.o)
uuid_generate                       /opt/zmq/out/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-uuid.o)
setsockopt                          /opt/zmq/out/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-tcp_listener.o)
getaddrinfo                         /opt/zmq/out/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o)
freeaddrinfo                        /opt/zmq/out/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o)
__xnet_socketpair                   /opt/zmq/out/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-signaler.o)
__xnet_bind                         /opt/zmq/out/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-tcp_listener.o)
uuid_unparse                        /opt/zmq/out/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-uuid.o)
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to zclient
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong, or provide me with an alternative method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the libraries:

```
-lsocket -lnsl -luuid
```

are standard on linux but not on solaris and need to be included in the Makefile like so:

```
g++ -lsocket -lnsl -luuid  zmqclient.cpp /home/xx/out/lib/libzmq.a   -o zmqclient
```